# Python division off by a lot? Why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a value based on the division of two other values. Here, "Cases vs Density" (2462.461176) is just "Cases" (81) divided by "Density" (0.03). This should result in 2700, but it gives 2462.461176.
These values are produced by a function that aggregates the values from multiple dataframes and creates a list out of the data. It's then used in a for loop to create a list of these lists, and then I make that into a dataframe. Index here is fips. I'm just playing around with free covid and population data.

```
        County          State   Population  Cases   Deaths  Population Density  Cases vs Density
fips                            
2290    Yukon-Koyukuk   Alaska  5230        81      1       0.03                2462.461176
```

Cases vs Density is defined as:

```
cases_vs_density = cases / density
```

So here it should look like:

```
cases_vs_density = 81 / 0.03
```

Why is it doing this? If I do this in the interpreter (x = 81, y = 0.03, r = x / r, print(r)) I get the correct value! Why is it only giving the wrong value when I run it through my function? Here is the function:

```
def totaler(fips_id):
    value_list = county_covid[county_covid['fips'] == fips_id].iloc[-1:, :].values[0]
    county = value_list[1]
    state = value_list[2]
    fips = value_list[3]
    cases = value_list[4]
    deaths = value_list[5]
    land = county_land.loc[int(fips)].values[1]
    pop = county_pop[(county_pop.index == state) & (county_pop['CTYNAME'].str.contains(county))].values[0][1]
    density = pop / land
    cases_vs_density = cases / density
    return [int(fips), county, state, pop, cases, deaths, "{:.2f}".format(density), cases_vs_density]
```

Comment: Clearly your `density` isn't exactly `0.03`, you're just displaying the first two significant figures!

Comment: print your values of cases and density within your function to see what they are. This will help.

Comment: 81/2462.461176 = 0.03289391962377075 that's what your density actual value is

Comment: @superbrain, population does not participate in this calculation at all. Not directly. They have calculated some value for density (i.e. population/land) but then just print 2 significant digits after the decimal point. And because we don't have land, this is ithe way to calculate what actual value of density they work with.

Comment: I say "not directly". If we know land and population - we can check that acual density is not 0.03. But we don't know land. So we work from the end. we know cases/density is 2462.461176 and from there we can find density by dividing 81 to 2462.461176. Simple math

Comment: @buran Yeah yeah, I was trying to determine land to get a more accurate result and for some reason assumed it would be an integer, that was my mistake.

Comment: @buran Was just curious because 2462.461176 probably isn't exact, so what you computed also probably isn't the actual (exact) value (and showing it with so many digits somewhat makes it look like you're going for exactness).

Comment: cases_vs_density is printed without being truncated, so it's exact. You can check that 81/0.03289391962377075 = 2462.461176. I admit in some cases there may be possibility for small discrepancy due to floating-point calculations, but not in this case

Comment: I updated it and the answer is much better. Pop density is 0.03289392.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are totally right, I forgot I was just displaying only to the second decimal place. I thought some weird math stuff was going on under the hood. The answer it gave is correct, thanks guys.